# Cassandra 2.x: secondary index on a unique value

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Let's say I have a user with an `id` and `email` fields, both are unique, and I want to query by both of them. `id` will be part of the primary key, but the question is what to do with `email`.

The first option is to create a "manual index", something like an `email_to_user` table. There the `email` would be the primary key, so lookups should be pretty fast. However there is some overhead in having to keep the manual index in-sync with the primary table.

The second option is to create a secondary index. However, as [Cassandra's doc say](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html), secondary indexes shouldn't be used on high cardinality columns - and columns with unique values are certainly high cardinality. However, I also read that secondary indexes are implemented as a hidden table - so is there in fact any difference between the two approaches? (except having the table manually created or hidden).

Maybe having  a **unique** value for the secondary index is a different case than having a high-cardinality value? Or maybe things have changed in 2.x (most of the material on this topic in the net refers to 0.x or 1.x versions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc you mention states as well that it is fine (regarding performance) to use a secondary index on a column that holds unique data as long as the query volume on that table is moderate.

### Differences

To answer your question in short: **Yes**, there are differences besides creating and maintaining the index table manually.

For more details, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248458/what-is-the-difference-between-a-secondary-index-and-an-inverted-index-in-cassan). Though it is from 2013 I think the answer is still valid.

In addition visit the [FAQ on secondary indexes](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/SecondaryIndexes).

p.s. to give you a more sophisticated answer you might want to share more details on your specific use case such as read and write load, data volume or queries making use of the secondary index.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! I don't have yet exact usage projections, was just wondering in general.